# Text match library in php

Tags: php

Is there any library in php using which I can match words like "expression" and "expresion" with some levels of confidence?

In short given a user entered word I want to match it with the 1000 words I've in the list and find the closest match with an indication of how close it is.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208743/php-fuzzy-search-matching

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the similar_text() function?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: What about soundex and levenshtein functions?

Comment: Both of those functions can compliment the similar_text function in trying to find possible matches.