# Merge facebook, twitter and foursquare friends PHP, any suggestions?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, twitter, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

I have been working on fetching user's friends from facebook, twitter and foursquare for about three months using PHP and their respective SDKs. Successfully I fetched the friends list and I stored each list in an associative array. 
I'm looking for ideas to combine these friends and come with with a similarity score?

The problem is I only have friends names and no other information. Facebook & twitter won't provide any other details even their respective email ids. I'm wondering if anyone has some on how to design a score function?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: You can do fuzzy matching in PHP, but it isn't that efficient. You would be better off using your SQL engine or something like Sphinx if you don't have a match on the email address. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3442649/1427161

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I'm looking at Sphinx now :)