# PHP MySQL search query - how to find result like "my search" when searching "mysearch"?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I havent been able to find the answer to this, maybe I have overlooked it, but this is a very simple question:

I have a search module for Joomla/Virtuemart and I have 1 problem with the search results generated by this module.

When I type this search word "**mysearch**" I want it to find all results with words that are part of the search query, e.g. title: "This is **my search**" or "What a nice **search**"

How do I accomplish this with MySQL?

This is my working code:

```
$ab = explode(' ', $keyword);
  $ccc='';
          $ccc2='';
          foreach ($ab as $k)
          {
            if (!empty($k))
           {

          if($ccc==''){         
          $ccc.= " concat(product_name, customtitle) RLIKE '".$db->getEscaped($k)."' AND";
                }
                else{
           $ccc.= " concat(product_name, customtitle) RLIKE '".$db->getEscaped($k)."' AND";
                }

                    if($ccc2==''){
          $ccc2.= " product_sku RLIKE '".$db->getEscaped($k)."' AND";
                }
                else{
            $ccc2.= " product_sku RLIKE '".$db->getEscaped($k)."' AND";
                }


       }
       else { 
       $ccc2.= " product_sku RLIKE '0' AND";
       $ccc.= " concat(product_name, customtitle) RLIKE '0' AND";
       }
    }

$ccc = rtrim($ccc, "AND");  
$ccc2 = rtrim($ccc2, "AND");    




$q ="(SELECT p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name
 from #__virtuemart_products p join
      #__virtuemart_products_".VMLANG." l
      on p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id
 WHERE ".$ccc." AND
       p.published = '1'
 LIMIT 0,".$prods."
)
union (select p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name
 from #__virtuemart_products p join
      #__virtuemart_products_".VMLANG." l
      on p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id
 where ".$ccc2." and
       p.published = '1'
 LIMIT 0,".$prods.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge....not possible with MySQL.

If you want true fuzzy matching, you need a search system designed for it. The [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) library is great for this and is used in some amazing OSS projects.

Check out [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

of the two I recommend [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was afraid of. I will look into the links you have posted and maybe I can use some of those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious how to answer your same question, and though I'm unfamiliar with levenshtein, I found this question which I believe is very similar to yours, answered with an effective approach.

Note: the other states this is ONLY ok for small data searches. Because it compounds repeatedly, you can imagine how costly it could be (CPU and Memory).

Stack Overflow Reference
[php (fuzzy) search matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208743/php-fuzzy-search-matching)

PHP Documentation:
[PHP:net levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: Thank you, Shaun. I will look into this. Unfortunately the application for which this search module is used is a webshop with more than 200 categories and 3000 products, so it must be light weight