# MySQL fulltext search results fine tune

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I have an InnoDB table with 5000 rows. Here is an example of my table named 'insitutes'.

```
id| name

1   | University of London  
2   | Department of Maths University of London  
3   | Department of Biology University of London  
4   | Department of Chemistry University of London  
5   | Department of Physics University of London
...
```

This is what my query looks like

```
SELECT *, 
      MATCH (name) AGAINST ('London University' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM  insitutes
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('London University' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

This is what my result will look like

```
Department of Biology University of London
Department of Maths University of London
Department of Chemistry University of London
University of London 
....
```

I want to get 'University of London' as the first result. Saying this I mean I want to get the closest match to the search query.

By playing with my data I found out that changing the table type to MyISAM and modifying the query to 'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE' will give me expected results. But I cannot use the table type MyISAM as it does not indexes words less than 4 charaters.

Comment: to get approx results, you may want to implement a textual distance function such as LEVENSHTEIN https://gist.github.com/Kovah/df90d336478a47d869b9683766cff718

Answer (score 0):

What ever letter We Can Use As Text. If U Have Problem Say Me More Clearly. Ok ?

I Think You Can Use Mysql Query Like This:

```
select 
    *, count(name) 
from 
    insitutes 
where 
    name like "%London University%" 
order by 
    name desc;
```

Once Check This If This Statement Works Say Me Else Define Your Problem More Clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can indeed control the minimum word size in your MyISAM fulltext index, with [ft_min_word_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len).

```
SET ft_min_word_len= 3
```

or whatever you need, will do it. You probably want to make sure it's set in your MySQL my.cnf file too, so if your server restarts it's still set.

Second, the word `of` in your search term is in the [FULLTEXT stoplist](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). You can't use it for matching unless you remove it from the stoplist.

And, if you *have* managed to include `of` in your index, notice that the department name strings contain it twice, which will boost their score.

If you change  FULLTEXT's configuration be sure to rebuild your index.

Third, as you know the order of your resultset comes from the [`score`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230129/mysql-fulltext-search-score-explained) assigned to each row by FULLTEXT.  FULLTEXT is designed as an assistance to human perception. It presents choices for a human to choose among, rather than precisely correct choices. Expecting perfectly predictable results from FULLTEXT is probably a mistake.

Comment: I am no godaddy shared hosting , so I don't have access to change the fulltext index length. Please note that its not a problem related to stop words or short words. I guess its related to the way mysql give scores in fultext searches.

Comment: You're right about the scoring. Search applications allowing the website owner to control ranking details are more complex than a dbms full-text search implementation. They have aliases, forced score settings, [stemming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and more.